# ffmpeg - Unable to find a suitable output format

Tags: ffmpeg

This is a part of my command:

```
-r 60 -preset medium -codec:v libx265 -ar 48000 -acodec aac -shortest -strict experimental -sn -vsync 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 30000000 -movflags +faststart  -x265-params high-tier=0:pmode=1:wpp=1:tune=fastdecode :bitrate=30000:fps=60:keyint=360:min-keyint=180:vbv-bufsize=30000:vbv-maxrate=30000:scenecut=0  -metadata title
```

and when i run it i get the following error:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for
>   ':bitrate=30000:fps=60:keyint=360:min-keyint=180:vbv-bufsize=30000:vbv-maxrate=30000:scenecut=0'
>   :bitrate=30000:fps=60:keyint=360:min-keyint=180:vbv-bufsize=30000:vbv-maxrate=30000:scenecut=0:
>   Invalid argument

I think there might be a missing space or something like that somewhere but i'm not too sure what's wrong with this syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really worthy of a proper answer, so: `...tune=fastdecode :bitrate=30000...`, there's a space there that should not be there.

Comment: @Casper Worth making an answer from that so others can easily see in the question listing that a solution was found.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Ok. Good point. I added one.

Comment: In my experience the "unable to find suitable output for…" error almost always means you've made a typo and it's treating part of your command as the output file name.

Comment: Yeah i know, i just didn't know where the typo was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...tune=fastdecode :bitrate=30000... 
                 ^^^
```

There's a space that should not be there.